# Opening Plots inside of a Loop in Python

Tags: python

I have a pretty odd problem when using matplotlib. I have a loop going through different cases of a model and for each case I want it to output the solved differential equation as a graph, then ask the user if they would like to continue graphing. Here is the code I am currently using (with just one case for simplicity):

```
import math
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.integrate import odeint

P1 = 100
P2 = 20
Pa = 14.6959
L = 11.811
D = 7/16
Ac= math.pi/4*D**2 
Ar = .0305 
ML = 2.2
MP = .31
v = .1
C = .95
k = 1


#Defines the Function to Solve the ODE
def dU_dx(U, x):
        return [U[1],(P1*Ac-P2*Ac-Pa*Ar-(1-C)*v*U[1]-k*U[0])/(ML+MP)]

i =0
U0 = [0, 0]
t = np.linspace(0, 10, 200)
case = input("What state is the loop in (1-4)?")
case = int(case)

#The While Loop to Iterate through states and output the graph of the ODE
while i < 2:    
    if case == 1:
        P1 = 100
        P2 = 20
        dU_dx
        Usol = odeint(dU_dx, U0, t)
        xsol = Usol[:,0]
        plt.plot(t,xsol);
        plt.show(block=False)
        answer = input("Continue to plot? (y/n) ")
        
        if answer == "y":
           case = int(input("Enter the new case number : "))
        elif answer == "n":
            i = 2      
        else:
            print("Please enter y or n.")
    if case == 2:
        P1 = 100
        P2 = 0
        dU_dx
        Usol = odeint(dU_dx, U0, t)
        xsol = Usol[:,0]
        plt.plot(t,xsol);
        plt.show(block=False)
        answer = input("Continue to plot? (y/n) ")
        
        if answer == "y":
           case = int(input("Enter the new case number : "))
        elif answer == "n":
            i = 2      
        else:
            print("Please enter y or n.")

#The code for states 3 and 4 are identical to the code for states 1 and 2, with different values for P1 and P2. I haven't written them yet, and including them would only make the could longer with no additional insights.
    else:
        print ("Inproper state!")
        case = int(input("Specify a new case number : "))
```

The plot function's two inputs are defined in a function outside the loop and work as expected outside of the loop. However, when the code is run, the code skips over the graph and then does not prompt the user for input and continues to run. I have managed to get the plot to appear by adding `plt.show(block=True)` below `plt.plot`, however after doing this, the code will still stop after showing the graph and not allow the code to continue.

The end goal of this loop is to plot the solution to an ODE, then ask if the user would like to plot another ODE of the same form with slightly different constants. How can I get Python to allow me to plot my function while still in this loop and allow for the switching of cases?

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: You need to provide values for `i` and `case`. Otherwise code is not working even for test purposes.

Comment: In my full code, i and case are both 1. I'm fairly sure the problem isn't it reaching that point in the loop.

Comment: There is something wrong with loop logic: If You input value other than 1 as new case number then while loop will run endless.

Comment: I think I explained the loop structure poorly. Case is a user defined input that accepts 1-4 as options. In this snippet of code, it only shows the first case, but an identical section of code exists for each of the four valid cases, as well as an error statement for other cases. The loop won't run endlessly because it can never be in an invalid state, at least from a standpoint of the case variable.

Comment: So to diagnose the problem sharing full code and expected result / behaviour is needed.

Comment: I've edited the original post to include the full code as well as a better explanation of what it is supposed to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you may be running using an IDE, the "block=false" parameter works fine when launched using my mac terminal and is working as you intend it to. IDEs usually don't allow that. Your code is perfectly correct.

Comment: Thank you! I didn't know using an IDE could cause things like that not to work. Looks like I'll be calling my files from terminal instead of running it through Spyder from here on out!